# How do identify a web server from a an app server- SharePoint 2013 Farm

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

Im trying to figure out which server is an app server/web server -

One is SP01 and the other is SP02 see below
Im thinking SP02 is a web server.

Thanks in Advance

**SP01**

```
Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 
Microsoft® Project Server 2013 

Access Database Service 2010 
Access Services 
App Management Service 
Business Data Connectivity Service 
Central Administration 
Claims to Windows Token Service 
Distributed Cache 
Excel Calculation Services 
Machine Translation Service 
Managed Metadata Web Service 
Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Incoming E-Mail 
Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Workflow Timer Service 
PerformancePoint Service 
Project Server Application Service 
Search Host Controller Service 
Search Query and Site Settings Service 
SharePoint Server Search 
User Profile Service 
User Profile Synchronization Service 
Visio Graphics Service 
Word Automation Services
```

**SP02**

```
Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 
Microsoft® Project Server 2013 

Access Database Service 2010 
Access Services 
App Management Service 
Business Data Connectivity Service 
Central Administration 
Claims to Windows Token Service 
Distributed Cache 
Excel Calculation Services 
Machine Translation Service 
Managed Metadata Web Service 
Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Incoming E-Mail 
Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application 
Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Workflow Timer Service 
PerformancePoint Service 
PowerPoint Conversion Service 
Project Server Application Service 
Request Management 
Search Query and Site Settings Service 
Secure Store Service 
SharePoint Server Search 
User Profile Service 
Visio Graphics Service 
Word Automation Services 
Work Management Service
```

Answer (score 3):

You are correct **SP02** is a web front end in this case. The service which makes a SharePoint server web front end is **Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application service**. If it is started in a server, it becomes web front end.

Comment: thanks Nadeem.So how will you know which service are on the app server then when its all listed on both.

Comment: The services will be available in all servers. However, it is the status (started/stopped) which determines the role. That can be checked by going into CA->Application Management -> Service Applications -> Manage services on Server.