# How to check if my SharePoint SQL server is a SharePoint web front end?

Tags: sql-server, front-end

How to check if my SharePoint SQL server is a SharePoint web front end?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The service which makes a SharePoint server web front end is **Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Web Application service**. If it is started in a server, it becomes web front end.

The services will be available in all servers. However, it is the status (started/stopped) which determines the role. That can be checked by going into CA->Application Management -> Service Applications -> Manage services on Server.

Reference: [How do identify a web server from a an app server- SharePoint 2013 Farm](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/129871/how-do-identify-a-web-server-from-a-an-app-server-sharepoint-2013-farm)